# Composer error - Class not found

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Controller\Error' not found in /var/sites/t/websitename/app/lib/Loader.php on line 36

This is the content of the file in question:

```
<?php
namespace Lib;

use Controller\Login;
use Controller\Supervisor;
use Controller\Traffic;
use Controller\Error;

class Loader
{
private $_controller;
private $_urlvalues;

// store the URL values on object creation
public function __construct($urlvalues)
{
    if (! isset($urlvalues['controller'])) {
        $this->_urlvalues  = $urlvalues;
        $this->_urlvalues['controller'] = 'Login';
        $this->_controller = '\\Controller\\Login';
    } else {
        $this->_urlvalues  = $urlvalues;
        $this->_controller = '\\Controller\\' .
            $this->_urlvalues['controller'];
    }
}

// establish the requested controller as an object
public function CreateController()
{
    // does the class exist?
    if (class_exists($this->_controller)) {
        return new $this->_controller($this->_urlvalues);
    } else {
        // bad controller error
        return new \Controller\Error();
    }
}
}
```

The following is my composer.json file:

```
{
"require-dev":
{
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.7.*",
    "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
},

"autoload":
{
    "psr-4":
    {
            "Controller\\"  : "app/controller/",
            "Core\\"                : "app/core/",
            "Lib\\"         : "app/lib/"
    }
},

"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
}
?>
```

The files are definitely present in the "app/controller/" folder, and the uppercase-lowercase is the same.

Can someone please help?

BTW the files in question are outside of my public_html folder (the one visible in a browser), might this be related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

```
use Controller\Error;
```

at the top, so you can just use `return new Error();` later.